# do port-channel members card module must be same?

Tags: cisco, port-channel

port-channel 1 is active.members of port-channel are TenGig 1/1 and TenGig 2/1.
must Card type and Model on module 1 and 2  be same?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not a requirement.

You have to ensure that they have same configuration (for instance: speed/duplex and other information).

Comment: And in accordance to speed; interface types need to be the same, for instance: 10 Gbit cannot be bundled with 1 Gbit or 100 Mbit etc. and vice versa 1 Gbit cannot be bundled with 100 Mbit or 10 Gbit etc.

Comment: @Cown That is true.